# Does Java Actually Escape Back Slashes how it claims?

Tags: java, regex

What I understand is that every backslash requires one more backslash to be escaped for regex. I have the following input String in Java:

`C:\\my\\drive\\application\\webapps\\ROOT\\classes\\there\\is\\a\\clazz`

to remove everything upto `classes\\`, I added the following regex in Java `replaceAll()` method:

`.*\\\\b(classes)(\\\\W\\\\S|\\\\/){1,2}\\\\b`

**Why i have added four slashes**

1. One backslash escaped to indicate that this is regex `\\`
2. One backslash escaped to indicate that the regex input is going as a java String `\\`.

But even with one set of doubled-backslash `\\` it doesn't work.

When I tried it on regexr and regexplanet, it seems to be working correctly for both unix/windows type of filepaths and gave me what I wanted. It showed me the correct `replaceAll()` results as desired.

But when I put it into the code, it's not working at all.

Actual code

```
String targetStr = someMethod.get(); // value is C:\\my\\drive\\application\\webapps\\ROOT\\classes\\there\\is\\a\\clazz

String replacedVal = targetStr.replaceAll(".*\\\\b(classes)(\\\\W\\\\S|\\\\/){1,2}\\\\b", "");

System.out.println(targetStr);
System.out.println(replacedVal); // same as targetStr i.e. nothing has been replaced
```

So how many times in Java do we need to actually escape each backslash to get this to work?

Comment: One more for regex, and those two require two more for the compiler if they're in a string literal.

Comment: @EJP           tried that already. Didn't work. I am not sure if the problem description is clear because people are downvoting without realising what the issue is.

Comment: Looks like you could easily avoid the RegExp confusion by using `Path` class...

Comment: According  to your question you tried one for the compiler, not two. You will certainly have to post your actual code.

Comment: @EJP            posted actual code

Comment: Well you're wrong already. The value of the received string doesn't contain double backslashes unless there is something seriously wrong upstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases of strings and escapes you should really show your actual code, an MCVE, not *explain* your code. Special char in regex: one backslash, actual backslash in regex: two backslashes, two actual backslashes in regex: four backslashes. Regex in java string: double all the backslashes.

Therefore one literal backslash means two backslashes to represent it in a String, means 4 backslashes to represent in a regex String. All "regular" special chars of regex like `\w` need two backslashes in a java String as well -> `"\\w"`.

It looks like your have exactly double the amount of `\` you should have in the regex. Only if you have a regex String and want to match a literal `\` four backslashes are correct.

---

Note regarding your code: you write:

```
String targetStr = someMethod.get(); // value is C:\\my\\drive\\application\\webapps\\ROOT\\classes\\there\\is\\a\\clazz
```

But that is not entirely correct, the value is

```
C:\my\drive\application\webapps\ROOT\classes\there\is\a\clazz
```

Only because your IDE displays it as a String it escapes the escape character `\` and shows double `\\`. If you would check the characters it has there is only one `'\'` between every two path components.